# MRJob using a different Python interpreter for local vs. hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

I'm using MRJob on machine `A` to launch MapReduce jobs on machines `B_0` thru `B_10`. The job has dependencies that require it to be run not with the default `/bin/python` (i.e. the output of `which python` on machine `A`) but with `/path/to/weird/python`, which exists on the `B`'s but not on `A`.

How do I tell `mrjob` to use `/bin/python` locally to launch the job, but `/path/to/weird/python` to run it on the `B`'s once it's in the Hadoop cluster?

The `--interpreter` argument seems to determine the interpreter for *both* local and Hadoop. Is there another option to specify them individually?

Or is there some reason that the interpreter used must lie at the same path on both machines?

Comment: Hi, downvoter, how could I improve this question?

Answer (score 0):

Add a shebang line at the top of your Python file(s) to tell the system which Python environment to use.

Using the env tag allows both the local machine and the Hadoop cluster to access the correct interpreter, without you needing to explicitly state the location, e.g.:

## !/usr/bin/env python

or

## !/usr/bin/env python3

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I don't think this solves my problem. I want to run it with `/bin/python` on local and `/path/to/weird/python` on the cluster. Are you suggesting that putting `!/path/to/weird/python` in my job files will cause my cluster to run them with that? I thought it runs them as `python job.py` instead of `./job.py`.

Comment: Hi Eli, is /path/to/weird/python the default Python environment on your Hadoop cluster? If so, having !/usr/bin/env python in the .py file will run it from /path/to/weird/python on your Hadoop cluster, and from /bin/python when launching locally.

Comment: It is not, unfortunately.